# Update WooCommerce Order from Processing to Complete using seperate database

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Bit lost here, so help would be appreciated.
I use TutorLMS, and manual payments. This is the scenario:

1. Student buys course.
2. WooCommerce sets order to processing, that is exactly what I want.
3. Tutor checks order and then checks if payment has been received.
4. If payment has been received Tutor changes Order Status to complete and presses update.
5. Student gets enrolled in the course automatically during that process.
   That is all working the way I want it.

Not all Tutors have access to the back-end (eg wp-admin and/or orders) so I made a table that lists ONLY those orders that apply to the tutor who has no back-end access.
The table has orderID as field.

When I parse the orderID into $order_id using the code below.

```
/**
 * Auto Complete all WooCommerce orders.
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
```

I would have expected the order to be completed, however, it does not.... what am I doing wrong?

Ideally I have the function/code looking at tableA, get the $orderID and update Woocommerce order, so it will do the same thing as when I manually update the order status and press update using the back-end.

Comment: have you tried puting priority ? add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order', 10, 1 ); If you debug do you get the $order_id ? Do you get order object ? If not try like this maybe $order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); ? Not sure but 'completed' should be 'wc-completed' or not ? i have to double check.

Comment: Thanks Ill try that will report back soon